# Delete tables from SDE including archive-tables

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase

I want to delete some tables from my SDE as well as some featureclasses located in a feature-dataset. As some of those tables and featureClasses are enabled for archiving I get both the base-table/FC and its archive in two seperate steps. However I wonder if I cannot get both in one single step?

This is the code I currently use (**step 1**)

```
result = arcpy.ListTables(user + ".KS*")       # get the tables beginning with KS
for ds in arcpy.ListDatasets(user + ".KOM_*"): # get the FDS beginning with KOM
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(None, None, ds):
        result.extend([fc])
    result.extend([ds])
```

Now I want to append all the archive-tables also (**step 2**):

```
for ds in result:
    if arcpy.Describe(ds).IsArchived: result.extend([ds])
```

However this loop never terminates. Obviously everytime we find an archived table we add it to the result and re-iterate the whole loop.

After all I delete all the datasets within my list using

```
for ds in result:
    arcpy.Delete_management(ds)
```

Does anyone know how I may add the archive-tables also to my list?

Comment: The correct terms of art would be "Delete archive-enabled feature classes from geodatabase"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution and it was quite easy. The endless-loop occured because I added the same dataset again and again into the loop. I changed it to `if arcpy.Describe(ds).IsArchived: result.extend([ds + "_H"])` and now it works.